# FastAPI - GET request results in typeerror (value is not a valid dict)

Tags: python, get, fastapi, pydantic

this is my database schema.

[image]

I defined my Schema like this:

from pydantic import BaseModel

```
class Userattribute(BaseModel):
    name: str
    value: str
    user_id: str
    id: str
```

This is my model:

```
class Userattribute(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_attribute"

    name = Column(String)
    value = Column(String)
    user_id = Column(String)
    id = Column(String, primary_key=True, index=True)
```

In a crud.py I define a `get_attributes` method.

```
def get_attributes(db: Session, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100):
    return db.query(models.Userattribute).offset(skip).limit(limit).all()
```

This is my `GET` endpoint:

```
@app.get("/attributes/", response_model=List[schemas.Userattribute])
def read_attributes(skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    users = crud.get_attributes(db, skip=skip, limit=limit)
    print(users)
    return users
```

The connection to the database seems to work, but a problem is the datatype:

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 7 validation errors for Userattribute
response -> 0
  value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
response -> 1
  value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
response -> 2
  value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
response -> 3
  value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
response -> 4
  value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
response -> 5
  value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
response -> 6
  value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
```

Why does FASTApi expect a dictionary here? I don´t really understand it, since I am not able to even print the response. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

**Pydantic 2 changed how models gets configured, so if you're using the most recent version of Pydantic, see the section named Pydantic 2 below.**

SQLAlchemy does not return a dictionary, which is what pydantic expects by default. You can configure your model to also support loading from standard orm parameters (i.e. attributes on the object instead of dictionary lookups):

```py
class Userattribute(BaseModel):
    name: str
    value: str
    user_id: str
    id: str

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

You can also attach a debugger right before the call to `return` to see what's being returned.

Since this answer has become slightly popular, I'd like to also mention that you can make `orm_mode = True` the default for your schema classes by having a common parent class that inherits from `BaseModel`:

```py
class OurBaseModel(BaseModel):
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class Userattribute(OurBaseModel):
    name: str
    value: str
    user_id: str
    id: str
```

This is useful if you want to support `orm_mode` for most of your classes (and for those where you don't, inherit from the regular `BaseModel`).

**Pydantic 2**

Pydantic 2 has replaced the internal `Config` class with a `model_config` field:

```py
from pydantic import ConfigDict

class OurBaseModel(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True)
```

This works in the same way as the old `orm_mode`.

Comment: Thanks in my case I had got code from another dev and he had typo `class config:`

Comment: Using the `orm_mode` in my parent class fixed it... THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by two things:

1. The reponse_model parameter in the path operation decorator, which defines the type/shape of response to be returned. Removing this will eliminate the errors you see, as it will remove the validation against what is being returned.
2. The internal Config class that is missing in your Pydantic schemas.

Make sure to add the Config class to avoid this problem, or at worst, remove the response_model parameter (which I doubt anyone would consider). Example is:

```
class ItemBase(BaseModel):
    title: str
    description: Union[str, None] = None

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

Adding this class allows Pydantic model to read data in non-dictionary format, thereby allowing you to return database model.

Checkout the [fastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#use-pydantics-orm_mode) for more